# Open up window in same window html

Tags: html, css

I have been working with html and css for about 6 months, and a very very little javascript.

I recently saw this site here: http://daegonner.com and i noticed if you click "vote" it opens up this window box, but on the same website.

How is this made?

Comment: That's an `iframe` in a `modal box`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some thing you need to do to have that look.
Firstly you need to create that small windows using css and html, by the way it's called modal (like this one http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
Secondly, you need to study javascript onclick events (you can refer here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp), which help the small window display when you click to vote link.
Finally, the content inside that box is up to you. The page which you gave embed the content from another page through .

Answer (score 0):

Look for `CSS Popup` or `Lightbox` on Google, you will finde something helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include the jQuery library within the `<head>` tag:

```
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And then download, include and use some of these plugins or whatever else you find.

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ (recommend - very good and easy to use)
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: OP doesn't *have* to do anything. Jquery is a library *constructed* from javascript. It would be *easier* to use it, possibly, but definitely not a *must*

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. It's not needed except if the plugin require it.